# can a mock interface be used to test if the integration works fine?

Tags: integration

We are aware that mock interface can be used for code coverage in integration related classes. However can they be used to actually test if the integration is actually working as it should?

Thx

Comment: They can be used to improve the odds that the integration will work. And note that you should not be thinking of code coverage when writing tests but rather thinking of the functionality you are trying to check. So if you know the remote system behaves in a specific way test to make sure your code generates the required requests and handles the expected responses. Then when you run against the real interface you should only be dealing with misunderstandings about the interface and not code that is not doing what you plan for it to do.

Comment: Yes.. You mean to say.. test using all possible requests and responses.. this way only misunderstandings would be left behind

Answer (score 2):

Mock interface should only be used for test class scenarios when you write test classes. they should in **no way be used to unit/system** test if the actual integration is working as expected.

Only when you hit the actual integration systems/their end points you get to test to your end to end functionality and make them work as per your requirement specifications

You test multiple things with the actual integration which cannot be/should not be tested with mock

1. Check if the end system connectivity is working fine
2. Mapping between fields is working fine
3. End system is returning the correct response
4. End system is performing well within the agreed SLA's
5. Test error scenarios to check if they are sending errors as expected and you are also able to handle it in apex end
6. Check if the data type,field length,validations,cardinality between different elements/child elements is working as agreed in the integration document specification

Comment: Thank you.. One more question here.. If I am to have an integration where only the production environment endpoint is available, how can this be tested in sandboxes.. is there any mock interface available?

Comment: You should ask them for a end point to test in their testing environment. if its only their production endpoint you wont be sure if their end point is working correctly. I wouldn't put anything in production unless i test. You can maybe ask them if they can expose another end point in production which can be used as testing end point if they just stay stubborn and dont give you a testing end point